# How to use triple-slash references for libraries in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to get Visual Studio Code 0.3.0 to recognize my JavaScript libraries. However, intellisense is complaining. Here's a repro:

1. Open Visual Studio Code
2. File > Open Folder (select a freshly created empty folder)
3. Add a file `mytest.js` to that folder
4. Download `jquery-2.1.4.js` (full/uncompressed) to that folder (appears in the side bar)
5. Enter this in `mytest.js`:

   ```
   var x = jQuery('body');
   ```

Result: squiggly green lines under `jQuery`. Note that jQuery is just an example, I've had the same issue with libraries such as KnockoutJS and QUnit, etc.

I've tried adding a triple-slash reference like so:

```
/// <reference path="jquery-2.1.4.js" />
```

Heck, it even autocompleted the `path` for me. I've tried varying the path a bit, e.g. a `./` at the start, but the result is thus far invariably:

[image: screenshot of end product with squiggly lines]

Hovering `jQuery` gives a popup saying:

> Cannot find name 'jQuery'.
>   `any`

Still squiggly green lines. I *hate* squiggly lines though. How can I get rid of them?

Comment: What's the error message associated with the squigglies?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Good question. I've added that info to the bottom of my post.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, does it do anything if you add a reference to the corresponding [Definitely Typed](http://definitelytyped.org/) Typescript file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You Need To Refefence the jQuery TypeScript Definition File.**

---

You need a **'typings' folder** in the root of your app or site.  **Within the 'typings' folder** you need a **jquery.d.ts file**.

Your reference to the file should be similar to the following depending upon where the file **reference is located in relation to the typings/jquery.d.ts** file and folder:

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts"/>
```

Here's a TypeScript Definitions File reference for Node.js:

```
/// <reference path="typings/node/node.d.ts"/>
```

The easiest way to accomplish this is to click on the green squiggly in VSCode then click the `light bulb` and select `Add /// reference to 'XYZ.d.ts'`.  This will automatically add everything you need.

In a comment above the [Definitely Typed](http://definitelytyped.org/) web site was referenced if you want or need to do this manually.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about VS Code, but regular Visual Studio often complains when you try to access "global" variables like this. I find that this pattern helps me to both avoid these warnings and keep my code more modular:

```
(function($) {
    var x = $('body');
})(jQuery);
```

This has the added advantages of keeping your declared variables (`x`, e.g.) scoped within the file instead of globally, and allowing you to safely use short names (e.g. `$`) for your libraries internally, while avoiding naming conflicts. It also opens up an easy migration path if you end up needing to use requireJS or something like that for dependency loading.

Hopefully it will also get rid of your green squigglies?

Comment: A nice pattern, and I was familiar with it, but wouldn't that still leave you with those pesky squiggly lines for `jQuery` on that one final line of code? (Edit: it does so in VSCode.)

Comment: @Jeroen: Well drat. In Visual Studio, this tends to make the warnings go away, but that's for a different warning than what you're getting.